# Do 'inq' and 'ink' sound similar?

Tags: pronunciation

Do 'inq' and 'ink' sound similar?

I want to register a domain name which is related to data (writing stuff). Is it okay to use 'inq' rather than 'ink'?

Comment: How about enque from which it stems?

Comment: Is *inq* short for *inquiry*?

Comment: no it is not same.. you must use `inq` for your purpose.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about ***Naming***.

Comment: Are you asking if the pronunciation is the same? I would pronounce them the same, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the pronunciation of the word *ink* and the fanciful term *inq* would be identical.

There are several words and business trademarks which use a final *Q* to produce a *K* sound: [*umiaq*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Umiaq), [*tranq*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tranq) (slang), and *Compaq*, to name a few.